# how can I clean this data type object and transform it to type float

Tags: python, pandas

```
                             Hight
0                       
1               1,82 m (6 ft 0 in)
2        1,74 m (5 ft 9 in) metres
3               1,88 m (6 ft 2 in)
4                              NaN
5       1,80 m (5 ft 11 in) metres
```

How can I transform column  hight to data type float to this, keeping NaN values

```
                             Hight
0                              NaN
1                             1.82 
2                             1.74
3                             1.88
4                              NaN
5                             1.80
```

Comment: Your solution works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
 df.loc[df['column'] == 0.0, 'column'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `mask` with `inplace=True`

```
df['column'].mask(df['column'].eq(0), inplace=True)
```

---

#### `np.where`

```
a = df['column'].to_numpy()
df['column'] = np.where(a, a, np.nan)
```

Comment: thanks a lot but it doesn't work as float is numeric and cant be transformed into Null or NaN. What I'm trying to do is transform data that conteins numbers type object into float but maintaining Null values. Not sure if I expressed myself properly

Comment: No, you haven't.  `np.nan` is a numeric object.  It is considered a `float` value.  At this point, I'm unsure what you mean.

Comment: I have a column that contains numbers and letters type object, that I managed to clean by using .fillna with ceros and removing unecesary characters and leave only numbers type float, although I'd like to keep null values as null instead of 0.00 that they just turned into. thanks a lot in advance

Comment: `fillna` does exactly what you are suggesting you **don't** want to do.  That is, that it replaces null values with zero.  I'll delete my answer to reduce confusion.

Comment: I have to do it in order to fill the values that are missing in the rows

Comment: "Values that are missing" Is the definition of "null".

Comment: if I don't do I can't clean the data

Comment: read this post [mcve] to give you an idea of how to ask such that you can make yourself clear.

Comment: I changed the question and tried to edit it, not sure how to make it presentable

Comment: It doesn't work as I first need to clean the data, thanks a lot for your inputs so far

Comment: how can I delete this post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205936/discussion-between-ruben-lfdz-and-pirsquared).